# Displaing a hidden panel using ComponentQuery - Ext JS

Tags: button, extjs, panel, component-query

I simply want to show a *hidden* panel on the click of a button.

Currently I have this code:

```
search: function(btn) }
   btn.up('panel').nextSibling().show();
   ...
```

Which locates the parent panel and shows() the next sibling of that panel. (I think I explained that correctly..?)

However, I feel it would be more efficient to maybe use the ComponentQuery to call the panel I want to show, as the layout of my application is likely to change down the road and that would alter the hierarchy of my components and their functions.

Here's my `hidden` List view(panel) that I want to show:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.metadata.List' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.metadatalist',
    title: '<center>Results</center>',
    store: 'Metadata', 
    ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give your panel a itemId

```
Ext.define('AM.view.metadata.List' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.metadatalist',
    title: '<center>Results</center>',
    store: 'Metadata', 
    itemId: 'targetPanel'
```

and use this ComponentQuery

```
search: function(btn) 
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#targetPanel');
    ...
```